# Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excepciones

Hola buenas noches no se si alguien me pueda orientar como solucionar este problema, en mi código traigo unas imágenes que están en la base de datos guardadas en blob, estas las manejo en la parte del cliente como un carrusel de imágenes y todas las demás me sirven bien. Hay una donde tengo una cantidad de 56 registros de imágenes y me agarra bien el carrusel.

El problema empieza y esta solo con este registro donde se encuentran 178 registros en el carrusel de imágenes y me marca ese error.
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1

He buscado y no encuentro una solución o algo que me pueda ayudar. Esperó alguien me pueda orientar de antemano gracias.

```
 protected void gdvResultadosConsulta_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            int lintIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            GridViewRow rowSelected = gdvResultadosConsulta.Rows[lintIndex];
            List<CDocumento> ldsDoc = new List<CDocumento>();

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("btnConsultarDoc"))
            {
                txtModal.Text = "openModal";
                string IdExp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rowSelected.Cells[0].Text);

                Session["IdExp"] = IdExp;

                try
                {
                    List<CDocumento> ltblDocumentoInvesdoc = new List<CDocumento>();
                    using (WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient wsDoc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                    {

                        CDocumento[] doc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient().plistObtenerTablaDocumento(IdExp);

                        bool lboolPrimera = true;
                        string lstrImagenes = "";
                        string lstrLista = "";
                        int lintContador = 0;



                        foreach (CDocumento lvardoc in doc)
                        {
                            CDocumento obj = new CDocumento();
                            obj.lstrFst135_DocName = lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName.ToString();
                            obj.lsrFst135_DocByte = lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte as byte[];
                            Session["lstrImagenes"] = lstrImagenes;


                            if (lboolPrimera == true)
                            {
                                lstrLista += "<li data-target=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide-to=\"" + lintContador + "\" class=\"active\" style=\" background-color: black;\" ></li>";
                                lstrImagenes += "<div class=\"item active\" style =\"overflow: scroll; max-height: 400px; max-width: 700px; text-align: center;\"> <div class=\"carousel - caption\"><h4>Imagen:" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + "</h4></div> <a download=\"" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + ".jpg\" href=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt\"></span>Descargar</a><img data-toggle=\"magnify\" class=\"d-block w-100\"  src =\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"></div>";
                                lintContador++;
                                lboolPrimera = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lstrLista += "<li data-target=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide-to=\"" + lintContador + "\" style=\" background-color: black;\"></li>";
                                lstrImagenes += "<div class=\"item\" style =\"overflow: scroll; max-height: 400px; max-width: 700px; text-align: center;\"> <div class=\"carousel - caption\"><h4>Imagen:" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + "</h></div> <a download=\"" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + ".jpg\" href=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt\"></span>Descargar</a><img data-toggle=\"magnify\" class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"></div>";
                                lintContador++;
                            }

                            ldsDoc.Add(obj);
                        }
                        ltrResultado.Text = "<ol class=\"carousel-indicators\" style=\"display: none; \">" + lstrLista + " </ol> <div class=\"carousel-inner\">" + lstrImagenes + "</div><a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide=\"prev\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span><span class=\"sr-only\">Previous</span></a><a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide=\"next\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"sr-only\">Next</span></a>";
                        Session["lstrImagenes"] = lstrImagenes;

                    }
                    if (ldsDoc != null && ldsDoc.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Session["ldsDoc"] = ldsDoc;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                       
                        ShowAlert("No existen registros de documentos.", "danger");
                        txtModal.Text = "";
                        return ;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   
                    ShowAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar recuperar las guias." + ex.Message, "danger");
                    txtModal.Text = "";
                }
```

Esto lo muestro en un modal que trae todos estos datos.

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="ModalDocumentos" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalDocumentos">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Descarga de documentos</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="mycarrucel" data-ride="carrosel" style="text-align: center;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltrResultado" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCerrar" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" class="btn btn-warning" OnClick="btnCerrar_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

y también un ocupo jquery tanto para el carrusel como para el intervalo en lo que se mueven las imágenes. Y también uno para el loanding de espera.

```
//Sirve para los botones de siguiente y anterior
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#mycarrucel").carousel();
                $(".left").click(function () {
                    $("#mycarrucel").carousel("prev");
                });
                $(".right").click(function () {
                    $("#mycarrucel").carousel("next");
                });
            });
            $('#mycarrucel').carousel({
                interval: 1000 * 10
            });

            //Para el loading de los botones de documento
            $('.btn').on('click', function () {
                $("#mdlLoading").modal('show');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.button('reset');
                }, 8000);
            });
```

Comment: De entrada como el error te dice, te estás quedando sin RAM, si estás cargando imágenes en base64, y estás cargando 178 imágenes pues de seguro estás sobrecargando la memoria.

Answer (score 0):

De entrada como el error te dice, te estás quedando sin memoria (RAM), si estás cargando imágenes en base64, y estás cargando 178 imágenes pues de seguro estás sobrecargando la memoria. Si no puedes usar imágenes físicas, yo diría que implementes alguna clase de paginación, en la que cargues la cantidad de imágenes que caben en tu contenedor, y de ahí irlas reemplazando, de esta manera solo vas cargando 5 a la vez. El problema es que harás demasiadas llamadas a tu api. Si quieres comprobar lo que te digo, abre el administrador de tareas y mira como cuando cargas tu aplicación tu navegador lleva la RAM al 100%.

Comment: disculpa y alguna idea de como agregar paginación ?

Comment: Pues la manera en la que yo lo haría es modificar la consulta sql para implementar la páginación, luego por el lado del front, habría que ver si hay alguna manera de saber por dónde va el carrusel. Podrías hacerlo con tiempo en caso de que vaya automático o por click dependiendo de si vas a permitir que alguien lo mueva.

Comment: ya añadi una paginacion pero me sigue marcando ese error se supone que se limpia o se deja nulo para que no mande a los registros pero hace lo mismp

Answer (score 0):

Agregue un modal para cada paginación igual solo lo manejaba con uno , pero me sigue marcando erro al llegar a 100 registros.

```
 <!-- Modal para ver documentos -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="ModalDocumentos" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalDocumentos">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Descarga de documentos</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="pag1" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
                                <!--parte 1-->
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="carousel slide" id="mycarrucel" data-ride="carrosel" data-interval="false" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrResultado" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <%--<div id="pag2" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <!--parte 2-->
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="carousel slide" id="mycarrucel2" data-ride="carrosel" data-interval="false" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrResultado2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>--%>
                        </div>

                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="active"><asp:Button ID="btnPag1" runat="server" Text="1" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnPag1_Click" /></li>
                                <li><asp:Button ID="btnPag2" runat="server" Text="2" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnPag2_Click" /></li>
                              <li><asp:Button ID="btnPag3" runat="server" Text="3" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnPag3_Click" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCerrar" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" class="btn btn-warning" OnClick="btnCerrar_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

En la parte de webform agregue lo siguiente:

```
    private void fvoidPaginacionDocumentos()
            {
                try
                {
                    List<CDocumento> ldsDoc = new List<CDocumento>();
                    using (WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient wsDoc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                    {
                        string IdExp = Session["IdExp"].ToString();
                        List<CDocumento> doc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient().plistObtenerDocumentoRango1(IdExp).ToList();
    
                        if (doc != null && doc.Count > 0)
                        {
                            bool lboolPrimera = true;
                            string lstrImagenes = "";
                            string lstrLista = "";
                            int lintContador = 0;
    
                            foreach (CDocumento lvardoc in doc)
                            {
                                if (lboolPrimera == true)
                                {
                                    lstrLista += "<li data-target=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide-to=\"" + lintContador + "\" class=\"active\" style=\" background-color: black;\" ></li>";
                                    lstrImagenes += "<div class=\"item active\" style =\"overflow: scroll; max-height: 400px; max-width: 700px; text-align: center;\"> <div class=\"carousel - caption\"><h4>Imagen:" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + "</h4></div> <a download=\"" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + ".jpg\" href=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt\"></span>Descargar</a><img data-toggle=\"magnify\" class=\"d-block w-100\"  src =\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"></div>";
                                    lintContador++;
                                    lboolPrimera = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    lstrLista += "<li data-target=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide-to=\"" + lintContador + "\" style=\" background-color: black;\"></li>";
                                    lstrImagenes += "<div class=\"item\" style =\"overflow: scroll; max-height: 400px; max-width: 700px; text-align: center;\"> <div class=\"carousel - caption\"><h4>Imagen:" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + "</h></div> <a download=\"" + lvardoc.lstrFst135_DocName + ".jpg\" href=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt\"></span>Descargar</a><img data-toggle=\"magnify\" class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\"data:imagen;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(lvardoc.lsrFst135_DocByte) + "\"></div>";
                                    lintContador++;
                                }
                                ldsDoc.Add(lvardoc);
    
                            }
                            ltrResultado.Text = "<ol class=\"carousel-indicators\">" + lstrLista + " </ol> <div class=\"carousel-inner\">" + lstrImagenes + "</div><a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide=\"prev\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span><span class=\"sr-only\">Previous</span></a><a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#mycarrucel\" data-slide=\"next\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"sr-only\">Next</span></a>";
                            //Session["ltrResultado"] = ltrResultado.Text;
                            if (ltrResultado.Text != "") { btnPag1.Text = "1"; btnPag2.Text = "2"; }
    
                        }
                        wsDoc.Close();
                        ltrResultado.Dispose();
                        ldsDoc.Clear();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ShowAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar recuperar los expedientes." + ex.Message.ToString(), "danger");
                    txtModal.Text = "";
                }
            }

Lo cual es solo un método que mando a llamar desde el principio aquí:

 protected void gdvResultadosConsulta_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int lintIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow rowSelected = gdvResultadosConsulta.Rows[lintIndex];

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("btnConsultarDoc"))
            {
                txtModal.Text = "openModal";
                string IdExp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rowSelected.Cells[0].Text);
                Session["IdExp"] = IdExp;

                try
                {
                    fvoidPaginacionDocumentos();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ShowAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar recuperar los expedientes." + ex.Message.ToString(), "danger");
                    txtModal.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Entra ahí y se dirige al método que mencione arriba una vez que se carga aparece el carrusel  y su paginación le doy clic al botón y me manda a la pagina que elija  por ejemplo la uno la tengo asi :

```
protected void btnPag1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtModal2.Text = "";
                ltrResultado.Text = string.Empty;

                ltrResultado.Dispose();
                //ldsDoc.Clear();
                fvoidPaginacionDocumentos();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar recuperar los expedientes." + ex.Message.ToString(), "danger");
                txtModal.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Al darle clic a la segunda paginación:

```
protected void btnPag2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtModal.Text = "";
                ltrResultado.Text = string.Empty;
                ltrResultado.Dispose();
                //ldsDoc.Clear();
                fvoidPaginacionDocumentos2();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowAlert("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar recuperar los expedientes." + ex.Message.ToString(), "danger");
                txtModal.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Y así sucesivamente, pero según tengo entendido que al darle el literal y ponerle el string.empty este se vacía para limpiar la memoria y puedan aparecer los demás pero no es así, igual intente con el dispose y el clear pero me sigue generando lo mismo. Alguien me podria orientar ya llevo días  cambiando a varios formatos y no doy, igual intentaba algo similar pero con las flechas solo del carrusel pero no me di la idea.